# How do join a table where a simple left join will produce multiple rows when the desire is to have a single row the data in a single column?

Tags: sql, join, subquery

Details:

I've got an order line table(oeel) where I'm left joining a serial number table(icets).  There is only one oeel line but there may be 6 or seven icets(serial#) lines returned for the same oeel.line. Instead of the query returning multiple rows of data for the serial number, we'd like a single row where one of the columns has all the serial numbers in a single cell separated by commas.

It would look something like this:

```
Order number | line number | Product | prod qty | serial1,serial2,serial 3,serial 4 |
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would also help.

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. PS How you can write it depends on your DBMS. But you don't give it. For code questions give a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for string aggregation.  The standard SQL is something like:

```
select o.Ordernumber, o.linenumber, o.Product, o.prodqty,
       listagg(i.serial, ',') within group (order by serial)
from oeel o left join
     icets i
     on o.? = i.?
group by o.Ordernumber, o.linenumber, o.Product, o.prodqty ;
```

Some databases use `group_concat()` or `string_agg()` instead of `listagg()`.

Comment: Thanks for this information.  Unfortunately, we are using a progress openedge sql db and the commands mentioned are not valid.  I've attempted to search for similar progress commands but can't seem to nail one down.  Any additional help is appreciated if someone know openedge sql.

Comment: @TonyBruckler . . . That information should be in the question, preferably as tags.  This answer uses standard SQL.